# Lock local disc C: from installing or changing files

Tags: windows-7, updates

I want to lock local disk C: so that in the future I won't be able to change or install anything on it. I want to be able to use the data because my OS is installed there but I don't want to install anything there accidentally.

The reason I am seeking this is because I don't want updates for Windows to install because it messed up my computer twice when I installed a fresh Windows 7 and then installed the updates.

I am using Windows 7

Comment: Attempting to run windows on a read-only disk, if even possible, would certainly cause more problems than it would solve. Why not simply use a local account with limited privileges?

Answer (score 1):

"Locking" the drive, preventing *any* changes will make the system unusable.  Windows needs to be able to write to the disk to function properly. You *can* disable updates - another poster put this method as an answer. However, I highly recommend against this. The updates are there to make your system more stable and secure. Now, you said an update caused a problem with your system. I would recommend installing them one by one. Hopefully you can find the one that causes an issue, then uninstall it. My gut feeling is that the update breaking your system is most likely an updated device driver (for your hardware) that is incompatible with your system.  If it were me try installing all updates for the OS and skip the hardware updates for now.

Again, locking the system is only an attempt to fix a symptom' not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**To disable Windows Updates:**

1. Start
2. Right-Click Computer
3. Properties
4. Windows Update
5. Change Settings
6. Set Never Check for Updates

As mentioned "locking" C to a read only state wouldn't really work since applications (besides the system itself) will try to write to it and fail. If your only concern is Windows Updates - simply change the settings as above.